# Finding the number of clusters using elbow method in k-medoids?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means

I get a memory error when I run this code.
[Memory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhhAC.png)

> def elbowKMediod(words_vector):
> num_cluster = [x for x in range(2,8)]
>
> ```
> squared_errors = []
> for cluster in num_cluster:
>     print(cluster, "Done")
>     kmediods = KMedoids(n_clusters = cluster, random_state=0, method="pam")
>     kmediods.fit(words_vector) # Train Cluster
>     squared_errors.append(kmediods.inertia_)  # Appending the squared loss obtained in the list
>     
> optimal_clusters = np.argmin(squared_errors)# As argmin return the index of minimum loss. 
> plt.plot(num_cluster, squared_errors)
> plt.title("Elbow Curve to find the no. of clusters.")
> plt.xlabel("Number of clusters.")
> plt.ylabel("Squared Loss.")
> plt.grid(True)
> plt.show()
> return optimal_clusters
> ```

Comment: What is the exact memory-error ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.